# What is the : in a Laravel route parameter?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, routes

In the codebase I am working on, the routes use route parameters. I noticed something interesting though. It looks like `{flight:id}`.

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/flight/{flight:id}', [FlightController::class, 'book'])->where('flight','[0-9]+');
```

I do not know what the colon `:id` does. Is this Laravel functionality?

In the controller, the book method does not query the model. It appears to just have the flight passed to it. Where is the model accessing the database?

**Controller:**

```
public function book($domain, Flight $flight)
    {

        return view('flights.booked',[
            'flight' => $flight,
        ]);

    }
```

In every example I could find online, the controller still accessed the model with a passed id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`flight/{field:id}` is Laravel functionality that tells Laravel how to construct the associated `Flight $flight` Model during Route-Model Binding.

By default, it uses the Primary Key of the Model (which is typically `id`), so if your Model is using `id`, you can just do `flight/{flight}` and `Flight $flight` will work.

If you want to use something else, like a `uuid` or `slug`, you'd modify it to `flight/{flight:uuid}` or `flight/{flight:slug}`, and `Flight $flight` will be constructed based on the supplied `key` and `column` value from your Database.

Documentation can be found here:

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#customizing-the-key

Comment: When will Laravel automatically resolve the model? Just whenever the type is called? Like in the case of `Flight $flight`?

Comment: Yup, it's called Model Injection. I don't know the exact behind-the-scenes process, but navigating to `/flight/1` (for example) will load a `Flight` instance, based on the `id` in the URL (1 in my example), available as `$flight` in the Controller Method. If you changed your code to `{flight:slug}`, and navigated to `/flight/air-canada-101`, it would load the `Flight` instance based on a matching `slug` column in your Database.

Comment: Actually it's called route model binding ;)